# navigation bar image hiding custom navigation bar button 

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationitem, navigationcontroller

I am able to give image to navigation bar and also changed image of navigation bar button item. For some reason navigation bar image, i guess, overlapped over navigation bar button image. Navigation bar button is functioning right when i click on navigation bar image at left but its not displaying over navigation bar image. here is the code ;

```
UIImage *imagebar = [UIImage imageNamed: @"schedule-strip.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: imagebar];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 190, 44);
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView;


UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back-icon.png"];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
UIButton* someButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[someButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[someButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
[someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backToMore) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem* someBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:someBarButtonItem];

[someBarButtonItem release];
[someButton release];
```

help me out.

Comment: Try imageView.clipToBounds = YES;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**use the code
[imageView addsubView someButton];**

I hope now u will see the button.Actually you are adding the left bar button item to default navigation bar and as u r creating somebutton it is not getting added on imageview which is overlapping your navigation bar.So by clicking on that area it is working but button is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Ketan did you check for image ? is image exist in your project? 
Why you are using frame and content mode property for Navigation bar title ? 
May this link Help you

http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/ios-5-customize-uinavigationbar-and-uibarbuttonitem-with-appearance-api.html

Comment: image that is used in project that u have mentioned is only one vertical strip (a line) and i have full image that given to navigation bar but the only problem is navigation bar button is not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"TopBg.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
```

extends @interface MyToolBar : UIToolbar and make object of MyToolBar. after that make your custom button for navigation bar. enjoy and like it